# Asymptotics of error function integral with square root

Tags: integration, asymptotics, special-functions, closed-form-expressions

I am interested in the asymptotics of the integral
$$I(a):=\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}\operatorname{Erfc}(x+a)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
for $a>0$. I think that $I(a)$ should be decaying exponentially as $I(a)\lesssim e^{-a^2}$ for large $a$. Numeric integration indicates that
$$ \lim_{a\to\infty} I(a) e^{a^2} a^{5/2} =C \in(0,1)$$
for some constant $C$.

Are there integral tables where I could obtain explicit expressions for $I(a)$ for finite $a$? If not, are the asymptotics above correct, and what is $C$?

So far I could only find results when the error function is integrated against integer powers of $x$ e.g. in Section 2.14 of [https://intra.ece.ucr.edu/~korotkov/papers/Korotkov-book-integrals.pdf](https://intra.ece.ucr.edu/%7Ekorotkov/papers/Korotkov-book-integrals.pdf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{Erfc}(x+a)\,\mathrm{d}x\rightarrow \frac{e^{-a^2}}{(2a)^{5/2}},\;\;\text{for}\;\;a\rightarrow \infty,$$
so $C=2^{-5/2}.$ Corrections are smaller by a factor $1/a$.
I obtained this asymptotics by integrating the large-$a$ expansion of the error-function,
$$\text{Erfc}\,(x+a)\rightarrow \frac{e^{-(a+x)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi } a},\;\;\text{for}\;\;a\rightarrow \infty.$$

Comment: Small correction: I followed your approach and found the next expansion term to be $-\frac{35 \  }{2^{13/2} \ a^{9/2}} \ e^{-a^{2}}$, i.e., smaller by a factor of $1/a^{2}$ than the leading term.

Comment: It is nice to find Bessel functions here.

Answer (score 2):

*Too late for an interesting integral.*

Using
$$e^{(a+x)^2}\, \text{erfc}(x+a)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\, P_n(x)\, a^{-n}$$ where the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(x) \\ 
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & x \\
 3 & x^2-\frac{1}{2} \\
 4 & x^3-\frac{3 }{2}x \\
 5 & x^4-3 x^2+\frac{3}{4} \\
 6 & x^5-5 x^3+\frac{15} {4}x \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using the above terms, the definite integral is given by
$$I=\frac{e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}}{64 \sqrt{2 \pi }\,\, a^{11/2}}\left(A(a) K_{\frac{3}{4}}\left(\frac{a^2}{2}\right)-B(a)
   K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{a^2}{2}\right)\right)$$ with
$$A(a)=4 a^2 \left(48 a^4+20 a^2-5\right)$$
$$B(a)=192 a^6+160 a^4-20 a^2+5$$ which is a more than decent approaximation (relative error smaller than $0.010$% as soon as $a>4.7$ and  smaller than $0.001$% as soon as $a>7.2$).

Expanded again
$$I=\frac{e^{-a^2}}{4 \sqrt{2}\, a^{5/2}}\left( 1-\frac{35}{16 a^2}+\frac{3465}{512
   a^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^6}\right)\right)$$